# Error in loading R package "GO.db" in installing WGCNA R package

Tags: r

When I have tried to install package dependencies of WGCNA, I have got the following error in the step of loading GO.db package after download completed:

```
biocLite(c("GO.db")) 
BioC_mirror: http://bioconductor.org
Using Bioconductor version 2.13 (BiocInstaller 1.12.1), R version 3.0.2.
Installing package(s) 'GO.db'
trying URL   
    'http://bioconductor.org/packages/2.13/data/annotation/src/contrib/GO.db_2.10.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 26094175 bytes (24.9 Mb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 24.9 Mb

* installing *source* package âGO.dbâ ...
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'GO.db', details:
call: match.arg(synchronous, c("off", "normal", "full"))
error: 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing â/home/zmousavian/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.0/GO.dbâ

The downloaded source packages are in
    â/tmp/RtmpBDs1Tq/downloaded_packagesâ
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages(pkgs = pkgs, lib = lib, repos = repos, ...) :
installation of package âGO.dbâ had non-zero exit status
2: installed directory not writable, cannot update packages 'colorspace',
'lattice', 'mgcv', 'survival'
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Do you really need this version or could you also use the latest one? Bioconductor is already at version 3.0, maybe you could first try the latest version and see if this works for you?

Comment: I have used the following command, and the version is not given by me!     source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")

Comment: Using `source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")` gives Bioconductor version 3.0.

Comment: Using this command, I give Bioconductor version 2.13, and a newer version of Bioconductor is available after installing a new version of R, how can I install new version of R in linux? What is the latest version of R for Linux?

Comment: It might depend on your distribution. You should check this here: http://cran.at.r-project.org/bin/linux/